# How to update document inside a document in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

```
{
"_id" : O5,
"bazar" : {
    "indiraBazar" : {
        "units" : "taka",
        "no" : 560,
        "value" : 0.90
    },
    "dhakaBazar" : {
        "no" : "no item",
        "value" : 1
    },
    "kolaBazar" : {
        "no" : "unlimited",
        "value" : 4
    }
},
"vat" : false,
"total" : 2
```

}

Say above document is under `bazars` collection. Here how will I set `value` filed of `kolaBazar` to 5 from 4?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The query would update as requested: `db.bazars.update({'bazar.kolaBazar.value': 4}, {$set: {'bazar.kolaBazar.value':NumberInt(5)}})`.

EDIT: That query also works: `db.bazars.update({'id': 06}, {$set: {'bazar.kolaBazar.value':NumberInt(5)}})`

But I would change the schema to ease your query.

```
{
    "_id" : "O6",
    "bazar" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "indiraBazar",
            "units" : "taka",
            "no" : 560,
            "value" : 0.9
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "dhakaBazar",
            "no" : "no item",
            "value" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "kolaBazar",
            "no" : "unlimited",
            "value" : 4
        }
    ],
    "vat" : false,
    "total" : 2
}
```

The new query would be `db.bazars.update({'bazar._id':'kolaBazar'}, {$set:{'bazar.$.value':NumberInt(5)}})`

Comment: You can do also 
`db.bazars.update({"_id" : "O6"},{$set:{"bazar.2.value":5}})`

if you know the index array

Comment: db.bazars.update({'id': 06}, {$set: {'bazar.kolaBazar.value':NumberInt(5)}}) is working for me. So could you please update your answer so I can accept it? And thanks for your nice suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Just treat them as `'dot.separated.nested.properties'`

So it would be `{$set: {'bazar.kolaBazar': 5}}` in your case

Comment: I don't want to set `kolaBazar` to 5 but the **value** field of `kolaBazar` to 5

Comment: Oh, sorry. Then it's {$set: {'bazar.kolaBazar.value' : 5}} Just separate nested properties with dots and it doesn't matter how deeply it's nested.